# Refresh Div Containing PHP Function

Tags: php, jquery, refresh

So I have the following code:

```
<div id="currentmotto"><?php mottoGrab($name); ?></div>
```

And what this does is it uses curl to screen scrape a users motto and display it on the site. What I need it to do is for that function to refresh every few seconds to see if the user has updated the motto.

I know with jquery I can use the .load('phpfile.php') but the problem then is if I put that function in that file, it no longer gets the $name variable as that is from another page.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't store the name variable as a JS varible, that way you cna send the $name variable to the server through an ajax call when you want to get the file to return it's data?

Comment: If I start a session in the original page and store the name in a session variable, will this run over to the loaded page?

Comment: If you start the session there too, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass name to phpfile.php via the query string:

.load('phpfile.php?name=THENAME');

Then grab the name from within phpfile.php using $_GET['name'] and stick it in the function.

OR

Make an AJAX request passing the name and update the page using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP is executed server-side, it doesn't change once the client loads the page. The only way to refresh a div without JavaScript is to reload the page.

I would try using AJAX to get the name from the other file and update the HTML with JavaScript